# How to calculate inverse modulo expressions?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How is $$PQ^{-1} \mod (10^{9}+7) = 400000004 $$?

where $P= 6$, and $Q= 5$

So far I was reading on modular arithmetic online, and most of the sites were relating to a clock analogy. Unfortunately, me being very naive (w.r.t modular arithmetic), I find it very difficult to relate the clock analogy to evaluate an expression like this.

Most of the articles were saying to find a number $x$ which multiplied by the given number $a$ would be equivalent to $1$. So do I need to literally go and find that magic number $x$ by looping through all options?

Comment: @RobertZ Updated the question with values of P and Q

Comment: @Tim510 So what? I am not asking for the solution. Nor for any hints w.r.t to the problem. It's just a simple and generic doubt related to modular arithmetic concept which I am not aware of. Infact, the problem's comment section redirected me to the modular arithmetic wiki page. But I am not able to understand it.

Comment: @Tim510  Your comment is quite misleading. The question is certainly not "part" of said competition. Rather, it has to do with understanding the modular notation used there. It would be polite to delete and rephrase your comment.

Comment: My apologies, comment deleted. The intent was to alert potential answerers so that they would assist in clarification and explanation of the notation used, rather than provide a walkthrough of how to calculate $PQ^{-1}$, since that is a large part of the problem.

Comment: @Tim510: The problem was definitely not focusing on modular multiplicative inverse. I'm sorry if you think it that way. But it is certainly not focusing on it. The question mainly checks how well you know graph theories and trees. Had it been the case that this question focuses on inverse, then after reading Bill's answer, I would say this question would have been super easy. So,I strongly disagree with your response.

Comment: @Tim510: Also, if some other day, someone asks how to find inverse of a matrix (which he may need to solve a problem, we will always have something to solve, that's why we ask questions), then it would be very improper to say that this person is cheating because finding an inverse is very generic and not specific to one particular problem, unless the problem is itself to find an inverse or specifically a homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${\rm mod}\ 10^9\!+7\!:\ \ \color{#c00}5\cdot 400000004 - \color{#c00}6\, =\, 2(10^9\!+7)\equiv 0\ $

which implies that  $\ \color{#c00}{\dfrac{6}5} \equiv 400000004$

Comment: Thanks, Bill. Got it now.

Answer (score 1):

To find the inverse of $a \mod M$.

What we usually do is to use  [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to find $x,y$ such that

$$ax+My=1$$

By taking $\mod M$,

we have $$ax \equiv1 \mod M$$

$x$ is the inverse.

Edit:

Since 
$$10^9+7 = 5(2 \times 10^8+1)+2 $$

$$5=2\times 2+1$$

Hence

\begin{align}1&=5 - 2 \times 2\\
&= 5-2\times(10^9+7-5(2\times 10^8+1))\\
&= 5 - 2 \times (10^9+7)+5(4\times 10^8+2) \\
&=5(4\times 10^8+3)-2 \times (10^9+7)
\end{align}

Taking $\mod 10^9+7$, we have

$$1 \equiv 5 (4 \times 10^8+3) \mod 10^9+7$$

$$Q^{-1} \equiv 4 \times 10^8+3 \mod 10^9+7$$

\begin{align}PQ^{-1} &\equiv 24 \times 10^8 +18 \mod 10^9+7 \\
&\equiv 2 \times 10^9 + 4\times 10^8 +18 \mod 10^9+7 \\
&\equiv 2 ( 10^9 +7)+4 \times 10^8 + 4 \mod 10^9+7 \\
&\equiv 4 \times 10^8+4 \mod 10^9+7\end{align}

Comment: Thanks @Siong. Could you please extend your explanation to the example in question so that I can related precisely. Thanks.

Comment: what is $P$? what is $Q$?

Comment: Sorry, My bad. I should have put those values. P = 6, Q= 5